# Excluding specific chunks from merge

Tags: git, merge

I’m using git for source control on a small project.  My expected workflow is to make a branch for each major section of functionality. Each branch will include the code being developed (along with any supporting code) and associated test code (I’m developing in Python and using doc test). To maintain a good history and provide test repeatability, I intend to commit both the developed code and test code on each branch.  Once the code for a particular functionality is complete and tests out properly, I will merge it back onto the main production branch.

However, I don’t want to merge the test code onto the production branch. Since this involves not including blocks of code within the files I do want to merge, how do I do this?  In searching for answers, all I’m finding is how to exclude entire files.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you will find a good workflow for this. I would suggest you separate the test code from the rest so that it becomes easier, as you say, to exclude entire files.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do your merge `--no-commit`, and after resolving any conflicts do a `git reset --patch` to strip out hunks you don't want before committing the merge result.  If you goof and forget to strip them, it's easy to do the reset after and `git commit --amend` it.

Comment: This is probably the best option for doing what the OP suggests, but I'd suggest committing the undoing of test code either before or after the merge as a separate commit anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`git cherry-pick` is what you are looking for. The easiest way would be to have your developed code and test code in separate commits on the same branch (good practice to have small, easily digestible commits anyway), then cherry-pick only the developed code into master.

> 1. Pull down the branch locally. Use your git GUI or pull it down on the command line, whatever you'd like.
> 2. Get back into the branch you're merging into. You'll likely do this by running git checkout master."
> 3. Cherry pick the commits you want into this branch. Go to either the git log or the GitHub UI and grab the unique commit hashes for
>      each of the commits that you want, and then run this command: `git
>      cherry-pick super-long-hash-here.` That will pull just this commit
>      into your current branch.
> 4. Push up this branch like normal. `git push origin master`

[Quick git cherry-pick tutorial](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/how-to-merge-only-specific-commits-from-a-pull-request/)